# C++/CLI --BYTE MANAGED *

Tags: visual-c++, syntax, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, visual-studio-2005

If in managed extensions c++ they mention

```
 BYTE __gc * p ;
```

what could be the equivalent syntax in c++/cli?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a managed byte array use e. g.

```
array<byte>^ byteArray = gcnew array<byte>(sizeofTheArray);
```

or (because of the influence of C++11's auto)

```
auto byteArray = gcnew array<System::Byte>(sizeofTheArray);
```

Comment: Well if you want to use a unsigned 8bit variable you could use System::Byte (C++/CLI alias byte):
  `System::Byte myByte1 = 0x00; //< stack variable`
  `byte myByte2 = 0x01; //< stack variable`
  `System::Byte^ myByte3 = gcnew System::Byte(0x02);`